# Using Office 365 with Parental Controls

Tags: office-365, office-online, chromebook, parental-control

I'm trying to set up a child's Chromebook with parental controls active. Given that Microsoft removed their apps from Chromebook, I'm trying to allow them to access office.com online version instead. However, even though I've allowed the sites which Chrome prompted, upon attempting to open any file the site drops back to OneDrive UI - which leads me to believe there is still some URL which chrome tries to open in background and fails

Question: what are the URLs which Office 365 needs unblocked in order to work on Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with a following whitelist:

```
*.live.com
*.live.net
*.microsoft.com
*.office.com
*.office.net
*.onedrive.com
1drv.ms
login.microsoftonline.com
```